# Python - Sequence not equal, but it is what I am expecting

Tags: python, unit-testing, console, sequences

```
def parse(self, input):
    input = input.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
    bits = input.split("=>")
    return bits[:-1]
```

Given `"a => \nb => \nc=> "` the output in the console is `["a", "b", "c"]` which is exactly what I want. I guess the console must be formatting the output, but I cannot explain why my tests are failing.

My unit test fails, stating that the result is `[["a", "b", "c"]]` when I perform `assertEqual` using unittest.

Can anyone explain? I'm pretty new to Python in the sense I've not touched it for a few years, and even then it was pretty limited experience.

**Test code**

```
subject = InputParser()
self.assertEqual(subject.parse("a =>\nb => "), ["a", "b"])
```

Cheers

Comment: Can you maybe show the code from your unittest too?

Comment: Post the actual unit test code please?

Comment: Duh, I've added the test code I was using too.

Comment: The parentheses of the assert call are unbalanced, i.e. there are two closing ones, but only a single open one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this using the module below, and my test passes just fine:

```
import unittest

class InputParser:
    def parse(self, input):
        input = input.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
        bits = input.split("=>")
        return bits[:-1]

class InputParserTest ( unittest.TestCase ):
    def test_parse ( self ):
        subject = InputParser()
        self.assertEqual(subject.parse("a =>\nb => "), ["a", "b"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I feel like a right idiot. The code did indeed work. The tests that were failing were named similiar to some other tests higher up the chain. In turn the result of the parser was being used in a new sequence. Doh. I accepted this as the answer as by you being kind enough to run the code it proved there was something else I wasn't seeing. Cheers.

Comment: Haha, sometimes we don’t even see the most obvious mistakes ;) Glad you were able to solve it!